# Minimum required hardware for Flutter iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

Im a flutter dev, ive always been doing Android-only, but a client of mine has requested an iOS version of his app, but i do not really have any experience with iOS dev with/without flutter.

I would like to know the minimum (budget-wise) and other better choices for hardware required for me to compile + test + publish my iOS app to the App Store.

I heard that i need to get myself a MacBook and an iPhone, but which ones should i get ? does it have to be the latest ? and what are the most important things i need to know to choose what i order.
Also, is it a better idea to get a MacBook or a Mac Mini ?
And do i really need an iPhone or the Simulator is enough for this ?

Also if there any other recommendations, tips, ideas, i would really appreciate it as it would help me a lot.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you need to publish your app on the App Store, having a Mac is a need, since you will need Xcode to do so.** The specs does not really matter, the latests Macs with Apple Silicon CPUs have great performance.

Using the Simulator should be enough, it provides all features a physical iPhone would use, such as *FaceID*, *Rotation*, *Shake the phone*, *Localization*, etc.

I had a friend of mine use a Mac Mini with the M1 Chip to code in Flutter, and it had good performance, keep in mind, you will need a compatible keyboard, mouse and monitor.

**Found Mac Minis with M1 Chip on Amazon starting $379.00 USD**, so you can start budgeting from there. That should do it if you do not plan to use the Mac for something else than testing your Flutter apps and release them to the App Store

Personally, I use a Macbook Pro with the M2 Pro Chip, I need that performance since I use it on a regular basis and as my personal laptop.

Hope that helps.